# Requisição ajax não retorna o que quero

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, postgresql

Tenho uma página de cadastro com um formulário, a pessoa digita o ano e clica no botão para buscar o cadastro. Com o ano digitado tenho que fazer a requisição para o PHP executar a query, retornar os dados e distribuir os dados para os campos do formulário.

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição simples. A página pega o ano base do formulário e envia uma requisição com o ano base retornando o resultado da query dentro do PHP. Eu não tenho experiência com HTML, PHP nem javascript e depois de semanas estudando como fazer isso cheguei até aqui. A requisição executa e retorna, porém o resultado não é o que eu quero. Usando $.post o resultado que sai no `alert` (eu to printando o resultado pra ver se ta retornando o que eu quero, vou tratar os dados da query distribuindo eles um para cada campo do formulário) é o código PHP do query.php ao invés de executar e retornar a query. Eu tentei usando $.ajax e o resultado foi ainda mais bizarro porque ele não só executa o query.php, como retorna o código HTML da própria página. Tentei fazer usando XMLHttpRequest() e também retorna o código ao invés de executar. Não sei o que to fazendo de errado. Socorro...

**Editado:** Arrumei o código com o `$_POST`e a tag `<?php` e a requisição funcionou. O problema agora é simplesmente tratar os dados. Não sei como retornar nem como tratar. Resumindo: Tenho a requisição que faz a consulta no BD e retorna para a página. A requisição não retorna (ou não executa, não sei). O `alert` do `$.post` não executa quando eu uso `json_encode`. Se eu retorno `text` ele só retorna `array` (vi a variável pelo F12 e o alert printa isso também). O que preciso é que no final de tudo eu tenha um array (ou qualquer coisa fácil de separar) para atribuir cada valor de coluna consultada no BD para o campo especifico do HTML.

Usando $.post:

```
$.post("query.php", {ano_ref: ano_base},
      function(retorno){
    alert(retorno);
}, "json");
```

Com $.ajax ficou assim:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    URL: "query.php",
    datatype: "json",
    data:{ano_ref: ano_base},
    success: function (resposta){
        alert(resposta);            },
    error: function(){
        alert("erro de req.");
    }       
})
```

Usando XMLHttprequest:

```
var xhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.open("POST", "query.php", true);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        alert(this.responseText);
    }
};

xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var string = "ano_ref=" + encodeURIComponent(ano_base.toString());
alert(string);
xhttp.send(string);
```

O query.php:

```
<?php

    include("conexao_postgres.php");

    $ano_base = $_POST["ano_ref"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM public.parametros_estaduais WHERE ano_base = $ano_base";
    $resultado = pg_query($dbconn, $sql);
    $resultado_array = pg_fetch_row($resultado, 0); // ($resultado)

    echo json_encode($resultado);
?>
```

Aproveitando, eu consigo retornar um simples array ou só o `json` mesmo? Tratar o `json` é muito difícil? Como eu disse, cada uma dessas colunas da query vai para um campo do formulário, só isso.

Comment: O seu PHP deveria iniciar com `<?php` e usar o `$_POST` ao invés do `$POST`. No lado do browser continue com o `$.post`. Depois disso atualize a pergunta com o resultado porque você não colocou o que faz a `pg_query`.

Comment: Isso resolveu o problema. Agora só quero descobrir como tratar os dados hehe... `pg_query` é função nativa que retorna um `resourse` de consulta ao BD. Percebi que tenho que tratar isso antes (ou dps, n tenho ideia). outra função nativa é `pg_fetch_row`, que a partir de um `resourse` gera um array com uma linha da consulta.  Mas agora a request só retorna algo se eu n usar o `json_encode`, sempre que coloco e mudo o `.post` para retornar um "json" não retorna nada e o `alert` n executa. Só preciso ter um array dos dados vindos do BD no final. Vou editar o post pra att a situação.

Comment: Pelo que entendi das funções do Postgre no PHP, você deve usar o [`pg_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php) ao invés do `pg_fetch_row` porque assim ele traz os nomes das colunas como chave e os valores das colunas como valor.

Answer (score 0):

A situação requer uma boa depuração. Use as ferramentas de debug do navegador para ver os erros que a pagina php está retornando.  Nos navegadores mais famosos, click com botão direito --> inspecionar elemento --> aba network. Assim você conseguirá ver tanto os erros retornados pelo codigo em php, quanto os do javascript.